# How to get public national holidays for Egypt and Indonesia

Tags: php, calendar

So far I have been able to work out in PHP national holidays for UK and USA using the following references.

​http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php

​http://damianoferrari.com/calculating-u-s-federal-holidays-with-php/

I cannot seem to find out how to work out the national holidays for Egypt and Indonesia.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I require it to return all holidays for the given year provided in an array.

```
public function getHolidayDates($startDate,$endDate){
        $s_y = date('Y',strtotime($startDate) );
        $e_y = date('Y',strtotime($endDate) );
        $holidays = array();

        if($this->site == "uk"){

            for ($i = $s_y; $i < $e_y; $i++) {
                $holidays[] = $this->calculateBankHolidays($i);
            }
            $merged = array();
            foreach($holidays as $value) {
                $merged = array_merge($value,$merged);
            }
            $holidays = $merged;

        }elseif($this->site== "usa"){
            for ($i = $s_y; $i < $e_y; $i++) {
                $us_holidays = new US_Federal_Holidays($i);

                foreach ($us_holidays->get_list() as $value)
                {
                    $holidays[] = date("Y-m-d", $value["timestamp"]);
                }
            }
            //Yii::log(print_r($holidays,true));
        }
        return $holidays;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this would be to grab a list of holidays from somewhere online and add it into your code then loop through it in the same way you are for the US Federal holidays
The timeanddate site has holidays for many countries.

http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/indonesia/

You could try something like this to get the list of holidays

```
function getHolidays($country){
//Url of Site with list
$url='http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/'.$country.'/';
//Use curl to get the page
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $holidays=array();
    $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    function tdrows($elements)
    {
        $str = "";
        foreach ($elements as $element)
        {
            $str .= $element->nodeValue . ", ";
        }
        //This pplaces the items into an array 
        $tempArray=explode(',',$str);
        //This gets rid of empty array elements
        unset($tempArray[4]);
        unset($tempArray[5]);
        return $tempArray;
    }
    foreach ($items as $node)
    {
         $holidays[]=tdrows($node->childNodes);
    }
//The first and secone items in the array were the titles of the table and a blank row 
//so we unset them
unset($holidays[0]);
unset($holidays[1]);
//then reindex the array
$holidays = array_values($holidays);
return $holidays;
}
```

With that function you can pass a country to that site and it returns an array containing all the holidays for that country.

You can view the array like this and copy it out and add it to your code.

```
$indHols=getHolidays('indonesia');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($indHols);
echo "</pre>";

$eqyptHols=getHolidays('egypt');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($indHols);
echo "</pre>";
```

You can then adjust the output array to match your requirements.
Obviously you wouldnt continually run this code on every request you would only use this to grab the array so you can add it to your code.

Although this would probably work for all countries on the timeanddatesite.